# Richfaces showModalPanel function not working in IE when called from Iframe

Tags: jsf, richfaces, portal

I am having a richfaces app where pages would show a modal panel with a "Pls wait" message whenever some ajax processing is done. This works fine in IE and Firefox if used in separate web apps, but when I try to embed one web app into another webapp(like portals) and do the processing, it works only until a point where only ajax calls are submitted from the page. The moment a non-ajax call is invoked, the modal panel doesnt appear on the screen until screen refresh using F5. Specially this happens only in IE and works fine in FFox.

Comment: I had read comments and resolutions that this issue would not occur once the richfaces jar is upgraded to 3.3.3 Final, but it didnt resolve the issue in my scenario. I had to resolve it by over-riding the javascript function for richfaces.showmodalPanel in my template.